# Installing allegro 4.4 on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: software-installation, 19.10, libraries, c

I downloaded the repository of allegro 4.4 from [here](https://github.com/dmitrysmagin/allegro), but i have no idea how to install it on ubuntu. I looked for tutorials, but i didn't find them. Could you tell me how to install it please?

Maybe there is a more confortable way to install it as for example writing a single command in the terminal (in this case the software should be downloaded from terminal)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This project appears to use `cmake` - install cmake and read [this](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/).

Comment: Hi @Jos thank you very much for your suggestion...if possible i'd like to use a simpler solution (2 or 3 commands in the terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install Allegro 4.4 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install liballegro4.4 liballegro4-dev allegro4-doc
```

Packages for Allegro 4.4 will also be available in the default Ubuntu 20.10 repositories.

The version of Allegro that you downloaded from GitHub was last updated on October 19, 2013. In Ubuntu 19.10 run the following commands to install the latest stable version of Allegro instead:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install liballegro5-dev allegro5-doc codeblocks g++ xterm gdb
```

The packages that are highlighted in bold text are optional packages for running Allegro with C/C++ in Code::Blocks IDE.

The same commands will also install Allegro 5 portable library for cross-platform game and multimedia development in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Expected results of `cd /usr && locate --regex 'allegro.*\.so'` :

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/allegro/4.4.2/alleg-alsadigi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/allegro/4.4.2/alleg-alsamidi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/allegro/4.4.2/alleg-dga2.so
```

Comment: now the outputs are (after installation and after the above command; the process doesn't finish): /usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied