# Installing Allegro 4.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB

Tags: apt

I've been trying to install Allegro 4.4 on Ubuntu and found this old question for Ubuntu 19.

[Installing allegro 4.4 on ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251140/installing-allegro-4-4-on-ubuntu-19-10)

I tried those commands which did not work for me today on 19.04, nor 22.04. I think the question/answer worked when posted, but is now outdated with regards to repositories.

Found this [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/liballegro4.4) which seems to me that it is actually available for 22.04, so I probably did something wrong when trying to install.

I have also searched online and in allegro docs and forums trying to find an up to date installation instruction, but I can't find one.

Does anyone know how to get Allegro 4.4 installed and running today on a recent Ubuntu system? Preferrably through `apt` but I'll try any other way if I can just find an instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The commands in the linked [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251140/installing-allegro-4-4-on-ubuntu-19-10) still work on Ubuntu 22.04.

The actual problem in my case was that I was using a Live USB flash drive, and it does not have the **Universe** repo [enabled by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081243/why-do-i-need-to-enable-universe-repo-in-18-04-isnt-it-default-enabled), so it has to be added first, by `sudo add-apt-repository universe`. After that, installation worked as described for 19.04.